# Charpit's Method with a condition for parameter

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Solve
$$\ p^2-3q^2-u=0 $$ given $\ u(x,0)=x^2 $ ,using Charpit's method to find complete solution.

I have tried to do the following, since the given equation is of the form
$\ f(p, q, u)=0$ 
as per Dover Books on Mathematics] Ian N. Sneddon - Elements of partial differential equations (2006, Dover Publications)

used the substitution 
$$\ p=qa $$
$$\ (qa)^2-3q^2-u=0 $$
$$\ q^2(a^2-3)=u $$
$$\ q^2 = u/ (a^2-3)$$
$$\ q = \sqrt(u/ (a^2-3)) $$
using this in given equation to find p in terms of q,
$$\ p^2-3[u/(a^2-3)]-u=0 $$
$$\ p^2=u+3[u/(a^2-3)] $$
$$\ p= \sqrt(u+3(u/(a^2-3)) $$
put the values in
$$\ du=pdx+qdy $$
$$\ du=\sqrt(u(1+3/(a^2-3)))dx+ \sqrt(u/ (a^2-3)) dy $$
$$\ du\sqrt u= \sqrt(1+3/(a^2-3))dx+ \sqrt(1/ (a^2-3)) dy $$
on integrating we get
$$\ \sqrt u=\sqrt(1+3/(a^2-3)) x + \sqrt(1/ (a^2-3))  y $$

Am I going right? If yes how to use the given condition $$\ u(x,0)=x^2 $$ to find a. Kindly help out.

Comment: Please write down what you have so far, starting with the Charpit equations. You should be able to integrate the relations between $dx$ and $dp$, and $dy$ and $dq$.

Comment: @NIRANJAN SARVADE : The solution is $$u(x,y)=\left(x+\frac{y}{2}\right)^2$$ If you cannot find it, edit your calculus and show where exactly you need help.

Comment: @JJacquelin  Got the same answer and also this one $$u(x,y)=(−x+\frac y2)^2$$

Comment: @Isham. You are right. $u(x,y)=\left(\pm x \pm \frac{y}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: @JJacquelin - I have updated the question. Kindly help me out.

Comment: @NIRANJAN SARVADE. You are welcome. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in 
$$ du\sqrt u= \sqrt(1+3/(a^2-3))dx+ \sqrt(1/ (a^2-3)) dy $$
It is not $du\sqrt u$. It is $\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$.

Do not forget $\pm$ before the square roots. The next equation should be $$ \pm 2\sqrt u=\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{a^2-3}}\: x \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2-3}}\:  y +C$$ 
You forget the $2$ before $\sqrt{u}$.

The condition is $ u(x,0)=x^2$ thus with $y=0$ :

$\pm 2\sqrt{u(x,0)}=2(\pm x)=\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{a^2-3}}\: x+C$

Thus  $\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{a^2-3}}=2$  and $C=0$. This gives $a=\pm 2$.

$\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{a^2-3}}=2$ and $\sqrt{\frac{1}{a^2-3}}=1$.

$$\pm 2\sqrt{u}=\pm 2x\pm y$$ 
$$u=\left(\pm x\pm\frac{y}{2}\right)^2$$ 
Or 
$$u=x^2+\frac{y^2}{4}\pm xy$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @ JJacquelin.